# Accommodating waypoints in a SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently creating a table to store taxi bookings.

[image]

**Key**

> Id - booking id
>
> CustId - id of customer who is being picked up
>
> DriverId - id of driver who is picking up customers
>
> PickupAddr - pickup location
>
> PickupLat - lat coordinate of pickup location
>
> PickupLon - lon coordinate of pickup location
>
> DropoffAdr - drop off location
>
> DropoffLat - lat coordinate of dropoff location
>
> DropoffLon - lon coordinate of dropoff location
>
> Mileage - distance between PickupAddr and DropoffAddr, including any
>   other stops made
>
> Stops - number of waypoints/stops during journey
>
> Price - what this customer has to pay for this part in the journey

The problem I am facing at the moment is that I don't know how to deal with waypoints.

e.g. if you've been picked up at A to go to B but decide to stop at A1 and A2 during the journey to pick some friends up (all pre-booked beforehand of course)

What would be the best way of restructuring my current table to accommodate this?

Should it come as a separate row or column? As this data is dynamic (i.e. one can't anticipate the number of pickups/dropoffs a customer makes mid journey), what should I be aiming to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a one-to-many relationship, it should be a separate table:

- `id` - Waypoint ID
- `booking_id` - FK to `booking` table
- `sequence` - ordering of this waypoint within the trip
- `addr` - address of waypoint
- `lat` - latitude of waypoint
- `long` - longitude of waypoint

If you want, you could remove the `PickupXXX` and `DropoffXXX` columns from the `bookings` table, and simply use the waypoints table for this. Pickup could be the first waypoint, and dropoff would be the last one.

Comment: Thanks - this makes perfect sense, very neat as well!